# Angular6, highcharts error "ERROR in node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128972,17) 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction'."

Tags: npm, highcharts, angular6

I am trying to configure highcharts with Angular6 by following steps :

```
Step 1 : npm install highcharts-angular --save
Step 2 : Add HighchartsChartModule in app.module.ts under imports
imports: [
HighchartsChartModule
]
Add import statement'import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';
Step 3 : npm install highcharts --save
```

After this when I build my application it gives me below error

```
ERROR in node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128972,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128982,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128987,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsTextPath'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128992,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsTextPath'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(136653,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotPackedBubbleDataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(136658,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotPackedBubbleDataLabelsTextPath'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(237720,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SeriesOrganizationNodesLayoutValues'.
```

my package.json looks like below

```
Package.json 

 "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
        "@angular/animations": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.1",
        "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
        "@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/material": "^6.4.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "6.1.0",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
        "angular-highcharts-chart": "^1.0.2",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "file-input-accessor": "^2.0.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "highcharts": "^7.1.0",
        "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "moment-business-days": "^1.0.6",
        "ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2",
        "ngx-storage": "^0.5.0",
        "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
        "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
        "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
```

I am really stuck with this setup !!
Any help is highly appreciated !! 
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install highcharts of version 7.0.3 worked for me.

```
npm install highcharts@7.0.3
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Change your high-chart version to 7.0.3

npm install highcharts@7.0.3

it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked for me to get rid of compilation error, I am looking for help in implementation of high-chart.
Please check "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570942/stacked-column-highchart-with-angular6-is-not-working" if you have any inputs/suggestions on this.
Thanks !!