# Stacked Column Highchart with Angular6 is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, angular6

I am trying to implement the stacked column chart for the first time with angular6 by following the Angular standard example from the link

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_highcharts/angular_highcharts_column_stacked.htm
```

But this give me blank container on the web page.
Is there anything needs to be added.

Below I am attaching my html and ts files for reference.

```
app.module.ts 

 imports: [
      ...
        HighchartsChartModule

    ],
```

```
.HTML file 

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">

    <highcharts-chart
        [HighCharts]="highcharts"
        [options]="chartOptions"
    ></highcharts-chart>
</div>
```

```
.ts file 

 highcharts = Highcharts;
    chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 250,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'], title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip : {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        credits:{
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Year 1800',
                data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
            },
            {
                name: 'Year 1900',
                data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
            },
            {
                name: 'Year 2008',
                data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
            }
        ]
    };


    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
```

Please share your suggestions/advice.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do you see a console error ?

Comment: Check this demo with `highcharts-angular` official wrapper: https://codesandbox.io/s/9ypy97xpmw

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I have tried the above solution, but surprisingly it is not working.
Only difference is I take off the below line from HTML as I was getting compilation error for security reason 
```
[oneToOne]="true"
```
Is there any other suggestions please !!
Please let me know if you want me to share any more information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean it is not working in your local environmental? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel yeah it is not working in local environment, and there is no console error too, and my local files are same as above in initial question post.
Please share you advice !!
Thanks !!

Comment: So, it has to be a different reason. Try to debug it.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel : Which one is right package for highcharts with angular 6? highcharts-angular or angular-highcharts?
Can you please re-check once package.json above, is there anything wrong you see, as I am really clueless what should I do here

Comment: Both wrappers are correct here. However, `highcharts-angular` is the official one. Perhaps you can reproduce your local app in an online code editor and try to show me the issue? Install the same packages and versions. I can't help you without any piece of code, demo or error message, sorry.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel: Thanks for all your comments and help, I got the solution.Please find the answer below.
I was adding imports to app.module.ts but should be under module specific files :)

Comment: I'm glad you've solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to get blank at web page is below : 
I was adding the HighChartsChartModule import under app.module.ts which is root level.
But in my project there are different modules, and each module have its own .module.ts file.
So if I add HighChartsChartModule under imports for specific module then it works as expected.
It never work if I just add under the app.module.ts

```
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';

@NgModule({
    imports: [

        HighchartsChartModule
    ],
```

Comment: You can import under your app.module.ts, but you need to add not only in "imports", you need to add in "exports", exports means that any other module can use that module, if you not export, only app.module can use it. If you import and export inside app.module, all modules will allowed to use